# iText 7 and C# writing a PDF file from MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, memorystream

I have a PDF document (using iText 7/C# 4.01) that I am creating in a MemoryStream and at the end, I want to write it out to a file. Part of the reason I am creating it in a memory stream is that I want to stamp a header table and footers on it at the end and was hoping to avoid writing it to a file then reading the file back in, stamping, then writing out a new file (as the examples I keep finding on iText website seem to do). However, I seem to be having some sort of chicken/egg scenario in the below code. It seems that you have to Close() the document in order for iText to fully form it. However, if I Close() it, then I get an ObjectDisposedException when trying to write it (simplified example below). I have to be missing something simple here, right? Thanks

```
    MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer.SetSmartMode(true));
    //writer.SetCloseStream(true);
    //pdfDocument.SetCloseWriter(true);
    //pdfDocument.SetCloseReader(true);
    //pdfDocument.SetFlushUnusedObjects(true);
    Document d = new Document(pdfDocument, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.LETTER);
    d.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));
    //d.Close();

    FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\test.pdf", 
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    baos. WriteTo(file);
    file.Close();
    //baos.Close();
    //d.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

I dont have IDE for test, but i think this work

```
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer.SetSmartMode(true));

Document d = new Document(pdfDocument, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.LETTER);
d.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));

d.Close();

byte[] byte1 = baos.ToArray();
File(byte1, "application/pdf", "C:\\iTextTester\\test.pdf");
```

Comment: I couldnt get the above to work exactly, but slightly modified, it did work! I used the below instead of FIle()     THANKS!                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\test.pdf"))
        {
                fs.Write(byte1, 0, (int)byte1.Length);
        }

Answer (score -1):

```
public IActionResult ExportToPDF()
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Initialize PDF components
        var writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        var document = new Document(pdf);

        // Add header to the document
        Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Soccer Player 2024 Goals Report")
                                .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
                                .SetFontSize(16);
        document.Add(header);

        // Create table for report data with 50% width for each column
        Table table = new Table(new float[] { 1, 1 })
                        .UseAllAvailableWidth(); // Spread the table to use all available width

        // Add column headers
        table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Player Name")));
        table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Goals Count")));

        // Materialize ReportData into a list
        List<BaseReport> reportDataList = ReportData.ToList();

        // Populate table with report data
        foreach (var item in reportDataList)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(item.Name)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(item.Count.ToString())));
        }

        // Add table to the document
        document.Add(table);

        // Close the document
        document.Close();

        // Return the PDF file
        return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", $"Report.pdf");
    }
}
```